# balanced incomplete designs

Tags: combinatorial-designs

My textbook said a balanced design with covalency 0 is a complete design.

I don't understand this, because

$$\begin{gather}
\text{set of varieties}=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}\\
B_1 = \{v_1\},\\
B_2 = \{v_2\},\\
B_3 = \{v_3\}\end{gather}$$
is a design that is regular, covalency $0$ for all distinct varieties, and is incomplete.

Why is a balanced design with $0$ complete?

Answer (score 1):

Is your textbook "Introduction to Combinatorics" by Wallis and George, by any chance? If so, it contains the following passage:

"A balanced design with $\lambda = 0$, or a null design, is often called "trivial," and so is a complete design."

In that sentence, they mean "A design is called trivial if either $\lambda = 0$ or it is a complete design." They do *not* mean "$\lambda = 0$ implies the design is complete."